# Excel2latex table running over page

Tags: tables

I have a couple of tables in excel that i would put in my thesis. From this forum I learnt I could use excel2latex to export them into latex. Unfortunately when i tried, it is not working out as it should. The table goes over the page. I tried using `p{with}` but then latex complains with lot of errors. I have also tried `save as Latex` in Gnumeric with little success.

Am I missing something? Here is an example of the table in excel and the resulting output from excel2latx[image: excel table]

[image: excel2latex output]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

excel2latex is afaik only able to use the standard column types like     l,c,r
you can manually modify the column type afterwards to     p{length} columns or you can use     tabularx and X columns that allow limiting of the table width to the available textwidth.

Comment: Hi thanks. O will give it a try today and see how it goes.